# How can I externally update a JavaFX scene?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am trying to learn JavaFX and convert a swing application to JavaFX.
What I want to do is use JavaFX to display the progress of a program.

What I was previously doing in Swing was first creating a JFrame with a custom JComponent. Then have my main program call a method of the custom JComponent that would change the colour of a shape within the JComponent and repaint().

The below gives an idea of the kind of thing I want to achieve in JavaFX:

```
//Run JavaFX in a new thread and continue with the main program.
public class Test_Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        Thread t = new Thread(test);
        t.start();

        //Main Program
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Click 'OK' to continue.",
                "Pausing", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        //Update Progress
        test.setText("Hello World!");
    }    
}
```

I currently have this as my runnable.

```
public class Test extends Application implements Runnable{
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Testing");
        stack.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 300, 250);
        stage.setTitle("Welcome to JavaFX!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();        
    }    

    public void setText(String newText){
        btn.setText(newText);
    }
}
```

Everything runs fine until I try to update the text of the button in which I get a `NullPointerException`. I guess this has something to do with the JavaFX application thread. I cannot find anything on the net though which describes how to update things externally.

I see a lot of mention about `Platform.runLater` and `Task` but these are usually nested in the start method and run on timers.

**UPDATE:**
Just to clarify I am hoping to achieve something like this:

```
public class Test_Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final boolean displayProgress = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]);

        Test test = null;
        if(displayProgress){    //only create JavaFX application if necessary
            test = new Test();
            Thread t = new Thread(test);
            t.start();
        }

        //main program starts here

        // ...

        //main program occasionally updates JavaFX display
        if(displayProgress){    //only update JavaFX if created
            test.setText("Hello World!");
        }

        // ...

        //main program ends here
    }    
}
```

Comment: You might find things easier if you try to learn JavaFX as a blank slate rather than trying to convert a Swing application to JavaFX (which IMO is a pretty hard thing to do for a non-trivial application).

Comment: Is the solution so simple then that I have missed something basic? I did start from scratch. But nowhere seems to describe this particular situation (maybe that is a clue that it is not possible!?).

Comment: It sounds like your real question is just "Is it possible to separate logical functionality from the UI?". The answer is yes: just create one class with the data and reference it from the UI if you're displaying a view of it. I updated my answer to show this; I'll leave the rest of the answer there for the benefit of those who might be searching for your question as you actually stated it.

Comment: @James_D My question was more "How can I 'add-on'/attach a JavaFX display to plot live the progress of an existing program/algorithm without dramatically changing the structure of the program?" Instead it seems that JavaFX has to be the main part of the program and logic run from the start() method. For example, suppose I want to optionally plot a time series while it is being calculated. The main program calculates the series using a for loop over time. It doesnt need any UI to operate and can just output to a data file. Anyway, I will accept your answer. It certainly explained some things!

Comment: I think the last example in my answer does that, no? The data is completely independent of whether or not there is a UI observing and displaying it.

Comment: @James_D Kind of, but in TestApp the 'main program' code is run from an `Application`. But in HeadlessApp it is run from `main`. Switching between the two is just kind of awkward in comparison to the structure I have with my Swing version (similar to my updated code above). I think though I will have to accept that. I am beginning to see how I can adapt your solutions (particularly your productionApp/launcher solution) to my full problem. Thanks a lot for all of your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` has nothing to do with threading (though you also have threading errors in your code).

`Application.launch()` is a static method. It creates an instance of the `Application` subclass, initializes the Java FX system, starts the FX Application Thread, and invokes `start(...)` on the instance which it created, executing it on the FX Application Thread.

So the instance of `Test` on which `start(...)` is invoked is a different instance to the one you created in your `main(...)` method. Hence the `btn` field in the instance you created in `Test_Main.main()` is never initialized.

If you add a constructor which just does some simple logging:

```
public Test() {
    Logger.getLogger("Test").log(Level.INFO, "Created Test instance");
}
```

you will see that two instances are created.

The API is simply not designed to be used this way. You should regard `start(...)` essentially as a *replacement* for the `main` method when you are using JavaFX. (Indeed, in Java 8, you can omit the `main` method entirely from your `Application` subclass and still launch the class from the command line.) If you want a class to be reusable, don't make it a subclass of `Application`; either make it a subclass of some container-type node, or (better in my opinion) give it a method that accesses such a node.

There are threading issues in your code too, though these are not causing the null pointer exception. Nodes that are part of a scene graph can only be accessed from the JavaFX Application Thread. A similar rule exists in Swing: swing components can only be accessed from the AWT event handling thread, so you really should be calling `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)` on that thread. In JavaFX, you can use `Platform.runLater(...)` to schedule a `Runnable` to run on the FX Application Thread. In Swing, you can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to schedule a `Runnable` to run on the AWT event dispatch thread.

Mixing Swing and JavaFX is a pretty advanced topic, because you necessarily need to communicate between the two threads. If you are looking to launch a dialog as an external control for a JavaFX stage, it's probably better to make the dialog a JavaFX window too.

**Updated:**

Following discussion in the comments, I'm assuming the `JOptionPane` is just a mechanism to provide a delay: I'll modify your example here so it just waits five seconds before changing the text of the button.

The bottom line is that any code you want to reuse in different ways should not be in an `Application` subclass. Create an `Application` subclass solely as a startup mechanism. (In other words, `Application` subclasses are really not reusable; put everything except the startup process somewhere else.) Since you potentially want to use the class you called `Test` in more than one way, you should place it in a POJO (plain old Java object) and create a method that gives access to the UI portion it defines (and hooks to any logic; though in a real application you probably want the logic factored out into a different class):

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class Test {

    private Button btn;
    private Pane view ;

    public Test(String text) {
        Logger.getLogger("Test").log(Level.INFO, "Created Test instance");

        view = new StackPane();
        btn = new Button();
        btn.setText(text);
        view.getChildren().add(btn);

    }   

    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }

    public void setText(String newText){
        btn.setText(newText);
    }
}
```

Now let's assume you want to run this two ways. For illustration, we'll have a `TestApp` that starts the button with the text "Testing", then five seconds later changes it to "Hello World!":

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // launch app:

        Test test = new Test("Testing");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(test.getView(), 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

        // update text in 5 seconds:

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                throw new Error("Unexpected interruption", exc);
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> test.setText("Hello World!"));
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

    }    
}
```

Now a `ProductionApp` that just launches it right away with the text initialized directly to "Hello World!":

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ProductionApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Test test = new Test("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(test.getView(), 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Note that there is an overloaded form of `Application.launch(...)` that takes the `Application` subclass as a parameter. So you could have a main method somewhere else that made a decision as to which `Application` was going to execute:

```
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 1 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
            Application.launch(TestApp.class, args) ;
        } else {
            Application.launch(ProductionApp.class, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can only call `launch(...)` once per invocation of the JVM, which means it's good practice only to ever call it from a `main` method.

Continuing in the "divide and conquer" theme, if you want the option to run the application "headlessly" (i.e. with no UI at all), then you should factor out the data that is being manipulated from the UI code. **In any real-sized application, this is good practice anyway.** If you intend to use the data in a JavaFX application, it will be helpful to use JavaFX properties to represent it.

In this toy example, the only data is a String, so the data model looks pretty simple:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class DataModel {
    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "text", "");

    public final StringProperty textProperty() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public final java.lang.String getText() {
        return this.textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(final java.lang.String text) {
        this.textProperty().set(text);
    }

    public DataModel(String text) {
        setText(text);
    }
}
```

The modified `Test` class encapsulating the reusable UI code looks like:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class Test {

    private Pane view ;

    public Test(DataModel data) {
        Logger.getLogger("Test").log(Level.INFO, "Created Test instance");

        view = new StackPane();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.textProperty().bind(data.textProperty());
        view.getChildren().add(btn);

    }   

    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }
}
```

The UI-baed application looks like:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // launch app:
        DataModel data = new DataModel("Testing");
        Test test = new Test(data);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(test.getView(), 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

        // update text in 5 seconds:

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                throw new Error("Unexpected interruption", exc);
            }

            // Update text on FX Application Thread:
            Platform.runLater(() -> data.setText("Hello World!"));
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

    }    
}
```

and an application that just manipulates the data with no view attached looks like:

```
public class HeadlessApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataModel data = new DataModel("Testing");
        data.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            System.out.printf("Text changed from %s to %s %n", oldValue, newValue));
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                throw new Error("Unexpected Interruption", exc);
            }
            data.setText("Hello World!");
        });
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply!
The `JOptionPane` won't be a part of the final program, it was just a placeholder that could block an immediate update to the button so the change could be better observed.
Further I was hoping that I wouldn't have to encapsulate the main program within a JavaFX application as I wish to optionally turn the 'progress bar' on or off at the start of the program. Thus potentially not using JavaFX at all.

Comment: Define all the logic in something that isn't a subclass of `Application`. Then define two application classes, one with and one without the "progress bar". Note there's also a [version of the `launch` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) that takes the application class as the first argument, so you could have a `main(...)` method that conditionally ran one or the other.

Comment: What would the purpose be of the application without the 'progress bar' if it isn't displaying anything? Simply to run the logic of the main program? Is it not possible to run the logic of the program without a dummy application? Thanks.

Comment: I was responding to you saying you wanted to "optionally turn on or off the progress bar". Let me update the answer to see if it clarifies...

Comment: Please see my edit. From your answer, I understand that anything like what I suggested in my edit is impossible. And that the main code has to be run from start() in order to gain access to the correct instance of `button` that is displayed by JavaFX. Correct?

Comment: Are you saying you might not want to show a UI at all? (That is hardly clear from the title of your question...).

Comment: Correct. Apologies for any confusion. I tried to keep the question as concise as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This code does what I think you're looking to do:

```
package javafxtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @author ericjbruno
 */
public class ShowJFXWindow {
    {
        // Clever way to init JavaFX once
        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShowJFXWindow dfx = new ShowJFXWindow();
        dfx.showWindow();
    }

    public void showWindow() {
        // JavaFX stuff needs to be done on JavaFX thread
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                openJFXWindow();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openJFXWindow() {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This isn't quite what I want. What I want to do is dynamically update JavaFX components from `main()`. I can get close by making `Button btn` a class member, putting `setText(.)` and `setOnAction(.)` into a new method `setBtnText(String newText)` then calling `dfx.setBtnText(.)` from `main()`. This eventually (it takes a while; isn't there a `repaint()` equivalent in JavaFX?) updates the label. The event handler is unaffected however and I get exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread`.

Comment: As you say "JavaFX stuff needs to be done on JavaFX thread". But I don't want to encapsulate all my non-GUI code into a JavaFX thread, I want to have the option to run my program without invoking any JavaFX at all. In your example I could do this by encapsulating the code currently in `main()` with `if(display){.}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling from within the UI thread as so:

```
public void setText(final String newText) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btn.setText(newText);
        }
    });
}
```

Anytime you want to make changes to an element of the UI, it must be done from within the UI thread. `Platform.runLater(new Runnable());` will do just that. This prevents blocking, and other strange obscure UI-related bugs and exceptions from occurring.

Hint: what you have read/seen with the `Platform.runLater` being called in the startup of the app, and on timers is usually a way to load most of the UI immediately, then fill in the other parts after a second or two (the timer) so that not to block at startup. But `Platform.runLater` is not only for startup, it's for any time you need to change/use/interact-with a UI element.

Comment: That's not actually the cause of the `NullPointerException` though.

Comment: @James_D yes, your answer is far more complete and correct. I'll +1 yours

Comment: I was about to say that I still get a `NullPointerException` when I try to implement this.