# javafx - game not updating changes to scene?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am making a Minesweeper clone, I am trying to create a new Board class when the user clicks on a mine thereby replacing the current board, but nothing happens when I create a new Board(). I tried to search online and the closest thing I can find is this [How can I externally update a JavaFX scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344172/how-can-i-externally-update-a-javafx-scene). I don't really understand the top answer and I need some guidance on a couple things;

- First (and the original question), how do I replace the losing game over Board with a new Board? **Board class line 90**
- Second (but relevant), is the way I'm creating this game even good design wise? I don't really know if I am following MVP or if I'm just barfing out code and trying to make something of the mess.

[Here is my Minesweeper clone on GitHub Gist.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f11ff33f67ab0851c3c5)

*EDIT: On user request, added some code snippets.*

The main start method;

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Minesweeper");
    Control admin = new Control();
    Scene sc = new Scene(admin.board);
    primaryStage.setScene(sc);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Where I create a new Board() in the Board class;

```
void display(Tile tile) {
    String display = String.valueOf(tile.surMineNum);
    if (tile.isMine) {
        // HERE IS WHERE I CREATE A NEW BOARD()
        admin.board = new Board(admin);
        display = "M";
    }
    else if (tile.surMineNum < 1)
        display = "";
    tile.setText(display);
    tile.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: Please post a small subset of the relevant code, we tend to not dig through entire code bases.  I recommend the section where the board is created initially and the section where you're making a new one.

Comment: Added those for you, let me know if this isn't enough.

Comment: Setting a new board to the `admin.board` field won't overwrite the one that got passed as a parameter to the `Scene` constructor.  The constructor took the argument it was passed and doesn't care if the source it came from changed.  Can't say much more than that since I'm unfamiliar with javafx.