# Changing Object Values During Runtime

Tags: java, javafx, runtime

I'm pretty new to JavaFX and I'm pretty confused how I can update objects during runtime in JavaFX. In the `start()` method, I can change and create elements as much as I want, and they are updated on the spot. However, if I do something like this, it doesn't work:

```
private static Circle circle;
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    /*
     * Large main circle
     */
    circle = new Circle();
    circle.setRadius((scene.getHeight() + scene.getWidth()) / 8);
    circle.setStrokeWidth(5);
    circle.setTranslateX(100);
    circle.setTranslateY(100);

    circle.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);
    root.getChildren().add(circle);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    launch(args);
    circle.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN);
}
```

Here we see we can't just change the values of an object outside of the `start` or `stop` method and expect them to change, and you can't call `launch(args)` multiple times.

I asked a question similar to this previously about changing the title of the window after it started. Nothing worked for me, but I did think that maybe I could run a thread in the `start()` method that sets the window title to a string that I can change wherever. I would do it like this:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            primaryStage.setTitle(windowTitleString);
        }
    }
}.start();
```

That didn't work for me though. There must be some way to change an object's properties after the start of the program. How can I do this?

**EDIT:** I found at [How can I externally update a JavaFX scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344172/how-can-i-externally-update-a-javafx-scene#answer-26344785) that I should just run all of my code in the `start()` function rather than even using a `main()` at all (except for launching). This is a solution, but is this good practice?

Comment: A call to `Application.launch` doesn't return normally until the JavaFX runtime has exited. Even if it did, the code after the call would be invoked on the main thread, not the _JavaFX Application Thread_, which means you can't just update the UI. When it comes to JavaFX, you should treat `start` as the entry point to your application.

Comment: What does “after the start of the program” mean?  Ten seconds after the window comes up?  Ten minutes after?  In response to the user pressing a button?  In response to the user pressing or clicking the mouse?